# Node JS aws-sdk getting 403 forbidden error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am now developing Node JS module and one of its functionalities is to show the files that exist in Amazon s3 bucket. 
Now I know Amazon AccessKeyID and SecretAccessKey, bucket name also. 
So, I wrote my code as follows.

```
aws = require("aws-sdk");
fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('config/amazon-s3.cfg', 'utf8', function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Cannot read Amazon Config file.");
    } else {
        config = JSON.parse(content);

        aws.config.update(
            {
                accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,
                secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey,
                // region: config.region
            }
        );

        var s3 = new aws.S3();

        s3.listObjects({Bucket: config.bucket}, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
            else {

                var contents = data.Contents;
                console.log(contents);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But when I run this code, I get always forbidden 403 error.

I tried it with several amazon accounts including my friends' accounts, so the amazon accessKeyID and secretAccessKey and Bucket info is not doubtful, but keep fails.

Can you please tell me what's wrong in my code?

Please help me!!!

Comment: did you configure http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-environment properly

Comment: Have you checked if your config object is correctly parse to JSON? And if the passed bucket name is properly spelled?

Comment: Speaking of config object parsing, it's correct, and I've checked it already.
Also I've checked bucket name and I can assure 100% for them.